# #ifdef WIN32 #include "stdafx.h" #endif в *.cpp файле

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Проблема со сборкой проекта в `VS2013` возникшая, видимо, из-за того, что студия ищет в файлах типа `*.cpp` первую строчку `#include "stdafx.h"`, а у меня из-за требований к кроссплатформенности надо инклудить другой заголовок.

```
#ifdef WIN32
#include "stdafx.h"
#endif
#ifdef __linux__
#include "stdinclude.h"
#endif
```

Можно ли как-то обойти эту проблему?

**P.S.** при сборке, в каждом `*.cpp` файле высвечивает ошибку:

```
ХХХХ.cpp(3): fatal error C1020: unexpected #endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете также отключить precompiled headers (в том же меню, что и в [соседнем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/565414/10105)), тогда требование, чтобы каждый cpp-файл начинался с `#include "stdafx.h"` уйдёт.

Учтите, что при этом уйдёт и ускорение повторной компиляции.

---

Visual Studio кэширует результат разбора header'ов, загруженных из stdafx.h, в *.pch-файле. Для этого ей требуется, чтобы строка `#include "stdafx.h"` была первой из «осмысленных» строк в .cpp. Иначе предыдущая строка могла бы по идее что-нибудь отключить или переопределить (а это повлияло бы на смысл кода в `stdafx.h`).

При компиляции Visual Studio отбрасывает всё, что находится в файле до `#include "stdafx.h"`, и заменяет своё состояние на содержимое *.pch. Новые версии Visual Studio должны выдавать как минимум предупреждение, если до `#include "stdafx.h"` встречается ещё что-то.

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете переименовать precompiled header в настройках студии:

С++ -> Precompiled Headers -> Precompiled Header File

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это не совсем то, что я имел в виду. Тогда уж проще на других платформах использовать редактированный под них файл `stdafx.h`

Comment: Я думал вам поможет переменовать stdafx.h в stdinclude.h, чтобы имена были одинаковые под всеми платформами.